# Hierarchical SQL query - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, hierarchy

I have a structure like this:

- Site

  - DocumentLibrary

    - Folder 1

      - File 1
    - Folder 2
    - Folder 3

      - File 2
      - File 3
  - DocumentLibrary 2

    - File 6
    - Folder 4

      - Folder 5

        - Folder 6

          - File 5
          - File 6

My Tables are the following:

[WEBSITE]
- websiteID
- websiteName

[DOCUMENT_LIBRARY]
- libraryID
- libraryName
- websiteID

[FOLDER]
- folderID
- folderName
- libraryID
- parentFolderID

[FILE]
- fileID
- fileName
- libraryID
- folderID

My question is...Given a SiteID and a DocumentLibrary ID how can i retrieve 
All the folders of a document library structure?
All the files of a document library structure?

Comment: To implement a hierarchy, you normally use another id field to indicate the parent. It is enough. Then, you can list all the items which have that parent id. i.e.: if DocumentaryID has an id of 9, you can list all the items which parent id is 9. To get deeper, you have to implement some kind of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on version you can use a CTE like MSSQL

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html